# Voltage Potentiometer 120v

Tags: voltage, potentiometer

I am looking for an inexpensive device with a potentiometer to slow down a fan and reduce the temperature of the heating element in a 120v hot air popcorn popper. This is an experimental project. Any feedback or suggestions are welcome. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could reduce the voltage to the device with a variac. You'd better know what your doing though. Post a schematic of the heater element control. Otherwise we probably can't help you.

Answer (score 4):

What makes you think reducing the voltage will help? It won't.

The temperature in a popcorn maker is regulated, most likely there is a simple bimetal thermoswitch which does a simple on-off regulation at a certain temperature. Reducing the power to the heating element will not reduce temperature but instead, slowing down the regulation only.

You have to find that thermoswitch and replace it with one of the same type but calibrated to another temperature.

After you have done that, it's safe to reduce the fan speed. The popcorn makers I know have a very small 12V fan. You could put a 9V voltage regulator into the fan supply, that would slow it down to about 50% speed.

Comment: +1 not only that but slowing the fan would increase the temperature.

Comment: Of course reducing the voltage will reduce the temperature. They use a resistive heater element to provide the heat, so if the OP added a TRIAC based power controller the temperature could be reduced. The problem is that once the temperature is reduced, the (likely) temperature sensor won't work, so you have to add another temp sensing element.

Comment: Reducing the voltage will reduce the power the heater has. The temperature will still be the same as it is controlled by the thermoswitch. It will take more time to reach the temperature. Usually, those popcorn makers are so cheap and simple they don't have a power adjustment. If they have a temperature adjustment, it's done mechanically.

Comment: *If* you reduced the voltage enough, you'd eventually get to low enough power that the heater (even if running continuously) would never reach the set-point of the thermostat. Changing the thermostat is almost certainly more effective, but a sufficient reduction in voltage *would* also reduce the temperature.

Comment: It will reduce the temperature if the heat loss is higher than the power of the heater. In all other cases, you get a simply a very long heating period.

Comment: Thanks to all you guys for weighing in.  It’s clear that reducing the fan speed is the opposite of what I am attempting to do.  The end result is to slow down the heating process.  Accordingly a higher speed and or a lower heating element would seem to be the goal.  I came across this: SCR Voltage Regulator adjust Motor Speed Control Dimmer Thermostat 110~120V AC (https://www.ebay.com/itm/222426782539?).  Might this do the trick?